# I'm building a website using the Edamam api from rapidapi. Back end looks great but no recipes appear on the front end

Tags: rapidapi, edamam-api

I'm building a website that used Rapidapi: Edamam. I'm using HTML, CSS, JavaScript, and JavaScript: Jquery. My project URL: https://github.com/Sbiggs1985/Hack_sprint

My code looks great on the back end. The front end has the search bar, when I search an ingredient nothing appears on the front end. On the back, the network is showing a big log of search queries. The console has no errors.

Any Advice? Please!

1. I've made sure the code has all necessary requirements to request the data from Edamam.
2. I've verified the API key is correct.
3. I made sure JSON is added correct to the object.
4. I've made sure all IDs match (I had that issue but got it resolved)
5. Added CSS to make sure front end is visible.
6. I've added console.log to see any output errors.

I've spent more than 30 hours and my project is due in a few days. I'd appreciate any help!